# Randomizing slides only works if more than two slides

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

I have this randomize() function to randomize slides in Slick Slider. It works, but in Firefox it only works if there are more than two slides. 
Can anyone see why that is?

Js:

```
  $.fn.randomize = function(selector) {
    var $el = selector ? $(this).find(selector) : $(this).children(),
      $pars = $el.parent();

    $pars.each(function() {
      $(this).children(selector).sort(function(chA, chB) {
        if ($(chB).index() !== $(this).children(selector).length - 1) {
          return Math.round(Math.random()) - 0.5;
        }
      }.bind(this)).detach().appendTo(this);
    });
    return this;
  };

  $('.slider').randomize().slick();
```

Html:

```
<div class="slider">
  <div>
    <img src="https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz2.png" />
  </div>
  <! -- Uncomment to see it working in FF 
   <div>
    <img src="https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz3.png" />
  </div> -->
</div>
```

[jSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/onuxhv47/3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to convert the `jQuery` object into an array using `get()` Use the shuffle code of this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2450976/2930661). And use `html` to update the parent `div`

```js
$.fn.randomize = function(selector) {
  var $el = selector ? $(this).find(selector) : $(this).children(),
    $pars = $el.parent(),
    array = $el.get();

  var currentIndex = array.length,
    temporaryValue, randomIndex;

  // While there remain elements to shuffle...
  while (0 !== currentIndex) {
    // Pick a remaining element...
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;

    // And swap it with the current element.
    temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
    array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
    array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  }

  $pars.html(array);
  return this;
};

$('.slider').randomize();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider">
  <div>
    1
  </div>
  <div>
    2
  </div>
  <div>
    3
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Happy to help :)